# When I try to import PyQt5, it says 'ModuleNotFoundError' even though when I install it, it says requirementalredaysatisfied

Tags: python, import, modulenotfounderror

I wrote the code as

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
```

but it is giving a module not found error

*I already uninstalled and reinstalled*

does anyone know any fix to this?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible that you have multiple instances of python on your system.

try one of these:

```
py filename.py
python filename.py
python3 filename.py
```

one other thing it can be is that installed it on an virual enviroment and are not using the python.exe from that enviroment.

in that case write the path to that python.exe like this:

```
path_to_python.exe filename.py
```

hope this helps.